# C++ deleting a list member while iterating: standard solution is not working?

Tags: c++

Here's my problem. I've read many previous questions about how to delete a member of a list while iterating over it and I tried the various solutions that the answers proposed. It happens that they seem not to work. I have a list of classes of this kind:

```
class Walker {
    public:
        Walker(int); 
        ~Walker(); 

        double *x; 
        double *y; 
        double *z; 
        double weight; 
        int molteplicity; 
};
```

The constructor and destructor are the following

```
Walker::Walker(int particle_num) {
    x = new double[particle_num];
    y = new double[particle_num];
    z = new double[particle_num];
}

Walker::~Walker() {
    delete x;
    delete y;
    delete z;
}
```

Now, the list

```
list<Walker> population;
```

is defined as a member of another class. Now, if the element molteplicity is null (calculated via another function) I have to dinamically remove the member from the class, and this is how I do it:

```
for( it = population.begin(); it != population.end(); ) {
        if( it->molteplicity == 0 ) {
            it = population.erase(it);
        } else {
            ++it;
    }
```

getting the following error at runtime:

> prog(22332) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f838ac03a60: pointer being
>   freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug Abort trap: 6

Do you see the error? Thank you very much for your help!! If you need some more code just let me know.

Comment: `std::remove_if` is a much cleaner way to remove members than this.

Comment: Use `delete[] x` etc

Comment: You use `std::list` but do not use `std::vector` instead of `double *`?  If you used `std::vector<double>`, your problem would more than likely never happened.

Comment: Surely there is also a need for a deep copy constructor here when adding to the list (or any other standard library container)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement **copy constructor,** because the list uses it internally.
The copy must be done when you execute code like: `list.push_back(Walker(5));`. The temporary object must be moved or copied to the list. 
Default copy constructor copies only pointers so destructor deallocate the same memory twice.

Also move semantic in this case is enought:
Please add this constructor to your code:

```
Walker(Walker&& other)
{
    x = other.x;
    y = other.y;
    z = other.z;
    weight = other.weight;
    molteplicity = other.molteplicity;
    //remove data from the original object to avoid freeing memory twice
    other.x = nullptr;
    other.y = nullptr;
    other.z = nullptr;
}
```

and remove the copy constructor (or implement it properly):

```
Walker(const Walker& other) = delete;
```

If you use pointers and allocate memory then you should know the rule of three:

> The rule of three (also known as the Law of The Big Three or The Big
>   Three) is a rule of thumb in C++ (prior to C++11) that claims that if
>   a class defines one of the following it should probably explicitly
>   define all three:
>
> destructor
>
> copy constructor
>
> copy assignment operator

Comment: The other answer is also correct but I think you have the real problem identified here - you should probably explain that deep copy is needed in the copy constructor though

Comment: Where is the copy constructor called here exactly?

Comment: @Jefffrey whereever he is adding instances to his `list<Walker>` (code not shown in the OP)

Comment: Thank you Adam. The problem lied in the copy constructor. Since I'm sort of new with C++ I never heard about it before and this morning I figured out how to build it and everything works fine!

Answer (score 7):

The problem has nothing to do with the use of `std::list`, but it's in the destructor:

```
Walker::~Walker() {
    delete x;
    delete y;
    delete z;
}
```

You have allocated using `new[]`, not `new`, therefore you have to use `delete[]` not `delete`:

```
Walker::~Walker() {
    delete[] x;
    delete[] y;
    delete[] z;
}
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15aa7024c87e71a1)</kbd>

Notice also that `molteplicity` and `weight` are never initialized and can therefore contain any number (likely different from `0`).

After those changes you program [compiles and runs](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15aa7024c87e71a1) perfectly.

---

Also notice that `new` and `delete` are generally frowned upon in the C++ community for very good reasons. Use smart pointers or containers, and please, generally follow the [rule of zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/).

And finally you can reach a cleaner solution using [`std::list::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove). If you follow these tips, you'll get something along the lines of:

```
struct Walker {
    Walker(int num) 
        : x(num), y(num), z(num)
        , weight(0)
        , molteplicity(0)
        {}
        
    std::vector<double> x, y, z; 
    double weight; 
    int molteplicity; 
};
```

and used as:

```
std::list<Walker> population {...};
population.remove_if([](Walker const& w) { return w.molteplicity == 0; });
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3ed1a27b0800eee)</kbd>

Which is both more readable and more correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. But still I get the same error!

Comment: @SimoneBolognini do you have a copy constructor and assignment operator?  Chances are good that as you add new `Walkers` to the list you are actually copying them and destructing the temporary original.  Thus you are probably deleting your pointers 2x if you don't have copy constructors.

Comment: @SimoneBolognini Quit using raw pointers.  See how easier this looks:  http://ideone.com/b81VM2  You don't need a user defined copy constructor, operator =, or destructor.

Comment: @SimoneBolognini You never initialize `molteplicity` and `weight`.

Comment: @dwcanillas I'm sorry but [no](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove). That's another `remove_if`, this one is `std::list::remove_if` which returns `void`.